# Retrieve/push many responses to jQuery from Web API

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Been trying to Google and see if there is a solution for my problem, but haven't found a good solution.

This is my current design.

- Upload .xml file to WebAPI server with jQuery.
- Process xml file and write to database through custom made class library.

  - Every entry in the XML will be validated and written to database through library.
- After one entry is written callback in Web API is invoked (Receipts) and stored in array.
- When every entry is finished, the receipts is sent back from Web API to client as JSON.

My problem is that a XML can have many thousands entries and it will then take a very long time to process. I'm wondering if it's possible to return/push a response (Receipt) every time the callback in Web API is called so angular/jquery can populate my view for every finished entry. As is it now, my $http-request can only receive one response, and that's when everything is processed and done.

Comment: Either you poll, or you use websockets -> happy googling!

Comment: I went with polling. Tho I had some problem to read from my receipt-list while another part of my code wrote to it at the same time. I think I solved it by returning a copy of the list before serializing the results to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use polling, i.e. ask in regular intervals to check if there are new data available, or use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), which is a technology that allows you to notify the client (browser) from the server.